# MFC: Delay when using GetContextMenuManager()->ShowPopup with Office2007 visuals

Tags: c++, mfc, contextmenu

I'm having a problem when trying to show a context menu (resource) on a right-click at the systray.

I've detected that this line:

```
CMenu menu;
menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU1);
HMENU hMenu2 = menu.GetSubMenu(0)->Detach();
--> m_pTrayMenu = theApp.GetContextMenuManager()->ShowPopupMenu(hMenu2, point.x-5, point.y, this, TRUE);
```

Stalls the program for about ~1.5 seconds. Edit: But only the first time this code is being run.

However, it only stalls if I have this line:

```
CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007));
```

If I change that to Office2003 instead, it works (though it doesn't get the nice visuals that I want)

I've tried looking on MSDN and different forums but it doesn't say anything about *Office2007 non-compatible with ShowPopupMenu().

I'm out of ideas. Can anyone help me shed some light on this issue?

Best regards,
Anton.

Comment: Can you step through the MFC sources for ShowPopupMenu() in the debugger and see if you can find a reason?

Comment: I found that this code-snippet is the one causing the delay: "CMFCPopupMenu* pPopupMenu = new CMFCPopupMenu;". Even if I put that directly into my software, it stalls (for the first time). So something with the CMFCPopupMenu and Office2007 is causing a delay. Probably on some sort of initialization stage.

Comment: I can't see any timer in the constructor `CMFCPopupMenu::CMFCPopupMenu()`, only in `CMFCPopupMenu::Create()` if you have animation on, that function is called only when you call `ShowPopupMenu()` -- do you maybe have animation enabled?

Comment: I don't have animation enabled (that I can see). I have made this Repro-project: http://lindgren.tk/TestMFC.rar - but I can't seem to find out why it stalls. I've also made a thread in the MSDN-forums, to see if anyone there knows why. I will report back asap. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten a response from the MSDN forums:

(after being taken to the devs, this is the response I got):

> As per the devs this behavior is by design. The delay is mainly
>   because of some XML parsing being done to load the office colors. The
>   color details are stored in an XML resource file.

The thread can be found here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/32d796a3-7b42-431e-9e1e-f58fb0dee0be/cmfcpopupmenu-and-cmfcvisualmanageroffice2007-not-a-good-match

Thank you all for your response and help.

My current solution is doing this:

```
CMFCPopupMenu *c = new CMFCPopupMenu;
delete c;
```

directly at the start of the program (thus having a ~1 second load before showing the main window).

Thank you all.

Best regards,
Anton.